# How to estimate the SQL Performance between UNION and OR Query Syntax?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to estimate the SQL Performance between UNION and OR Query Syntax?

I do see, results vary on these 2 syntax.

Which would be the better in performance?

Comment: This is way too generic of a question and depends on tons of factors.  Plus you need to provide what SQL technology.  Specifics help

Comment: Provide a sample code so that they can be compared against each other.

Comment: Actual query has bunch of joins. I wrote UNION for each set of Join Query results. Query output is taking few milliseconds. I tried with OR, results are varying. In general, UNION would be better than OR syntax in terms of performance?

Comment: @goofyui That question is probably a lot more complicated than you think. Generally you'll want to have a single query if you can help it. If there is no index on the column, and the query is doing a table scan, you can imagine that two individual unioned queries will do two table scans, while a single query with ORs will do a single table scan.

Comment: @RToyo , that help. It actually clarifies, why UNION query is taking much longer than OR query.

Comment: Show both specific queries, and then we can answer you.

Answer (score 1):

First from the point of view of execution

```
select * from some_table where col in ('A','B','C')
```

is same as

```
select * from some_table where col = 'A'
union
select * from some_table where col = 'B'
union
select * from some_table where col = 'C'
```

So now it comes to specific database and which route it prefers and how **smart** it is.  Union query will do an implicit unique check which may include an implicit sort as well but on small datasets that will be negligible.

Oracle, for example, will be able to optimize OR queries into UNION queries (internally) so from user's point of view they will execute in same time.

If you want a general answer; mostly the union will work faster on most databases because that is a simpler optimizer path.  But in same generality let the database do what you paid them for and always try to first write SQL which is easier to read and maintain.  Generally writing as union will take more lines of code so starting point should be with an OR.  If OR is not giving you same performance as union on a commercial database then see if you have some tuning parameters that are off.

Comment: i find some contradictions in your posting. One of the earlier comment says, Union will do table scan . While at the same time OR will do only once table scan. Considering that, OR syntax will be much better in performance

Comment: I am assuming that column col is indexed.  If it is indexed and selectivity is good then doing union will do an index seek 3 times in above example.  vs alternate will be a full index scan or a full table scan.  So in that case if #rows is high union route will consistently win.  If we dont have index or selectivity is not good then union will lose.  So that is why I suggest write query as it should be written and let db change it to concatenation (i.e. union). Refer to this oracle doc to see this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#6873

Comment: .. I think , in my case there is no index (or) selectivity isn’t good. I’m not able to share the actual query, this is my understanding based on comments

Comment: In that case "or" will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the Esimated execution plan to see what the query is doing.  You sound interested in performance and the more you indexed columns to avoid table scans the better your queries will run.

I use SQL Server 2012 and you can find 'Display Estimated Execution Plan' on the 'Query' Tab. Read it from Right to Left.  It will display the Index (type)Seek or Scan and cost %.  Hover each step to get a detailed summary.

Comment: Yes, please..Iam doing the same. Though, i was facing some end result count varying from UNION query to OR query.